# Where have my GIMP fonts gone?

Tags: fonts, gimp

Yesterday I has scores of fonts to chose from on GIMP, today I only have Padauk!!

Where have they all gone? I've not knowingly done anything with fonts etc. They are all there in Libre Office.

Ubuntu 18.04 / Gimp 2.10.14

Thanks

Comment: Which Gimp flavor? Installed from repo/PPA? snap? AppImage? flatpak?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gimp shows the packages available for supported releases, you've listed as using a version packaged for 20.04 so the packaging is likely key (eg. if snap packaged; is it classic confined? which can use your non-snap installed fonts, if standard confinement it'll use snap installed fonts..).  Your LibreOffice maybe packaged a different way - ie. @xenoid's question is spot on. If it wasn't snap, but was ..... *etc*

Comment: Upvoted because of an unmotivated (and in my opinion undeserved) downvote.

Comment: I installed it via the Ubbuntu software app. It says source is 'snap store' and there's a gimp directory in my snap directory.

Comment: OK - I've now opened  windows--> Dockable Dialogues --> Fonts and they are all there. They are just no longer in the dialogue box that pops up directly above the text box (where I can still change the size etc). I can live with this, but I don't understand why they have gone from here...